# upgrader: PlayStoreResults.redesignedVersion exception: Bad state: No element

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

when i use

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:upgrader/upgrader.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Upgrader.clearSavedSettings(); // REMOVE this for release builds


  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Upgrader Example',
      home: UpgradeAlert(
          child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Upgrader Example')),
        body: Center(child: Text('Checking...')),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

I just check other apps thats is worked but some apps show like that error not getting any `UpgradeAlert`

i want upgradealert but i did not get alert but i get upgrader: PlayStoreResults.redesignedVersion exception: Bad state: No element please solve this

Comment: same issue i also facing